# How to Find a record in Entity Framework without a Primary Key

Tags: entity-framework-core

I've got an entity:

```
public class Account
{
    public int AccountId { get; set; }
    public string Mnemonic { get; set; }
    public decimal NetAssetValue { get; set; }
}
```

On this entity I have a primary key (AccountId) and an alternate unique index on the mnemonic.

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    // Account
    modelBuilder.Entity<Account>()
        .HasKey(a => a.AccountId);
    modelBuilder.Entity<Account>()
        .HasIndex(a => a.Mnemonic)
        .IsUnique();
}
```

When I store my test data in an XML file, I have no knowledge of the value assigned to the primary key, so I need to find this record by the Mnemonic if I want to use it.
I know I can use LINQ:

```
var accountId = (from a in account
                where mnemonic = "Account1"
                select AccountId).First();
```

But will this use the index or iterate over the entire collection.  I could have thousands of accounts and don't want do be executing a table scan each time I want to find an account when I'm loading from my external files.

Comment: Why would this execute a table scan? It should use the unique index on `mnemonic` right? Also, you can use a `Contains` query to find all relevant accounts in one query.

Comment: I didn't say it would, I said I didn't want it to.  For a normal generic collections, LINQ will iterate over the entire collection to find a match.  While it's possible there's some optimization in Entity Framework, intuitively I would think that this LINQ statement would iterate.

Comment: It's not clear to me what you mean by the part *When I store my test data in an XML file...*. Which process do you refer to? Maybe you should show the code that envelops the `var accountId = ...` line, so we can see where `account` comes from and what it is.

Comment: @GertArnold - I'm speaking generically of storing canned data in some external files (JSon, XML, CSV, etc.).  I want to be able to make changes to the Entities or their relationships, then tear down the Domain (delete tables, relations, etc), then rebuild and reload the domain with the canned data.  The mechanics don't matter.  What matters is that I can't store the primary identifier (unless I'm using GUIDS) in the data files that contains the canned data, so I need to translate when I import data.  I can't use the primary key to find existing entities, so I need an index on the alternate key

Comment: Why don't you use in-memory database?

Comment: I'd like to move to an in-memory database at some point, but I'm trying to deliver an MVP using off-the-shelf products with solid .NET Core support, so I want to understand how to exploit EF Core.

Answer (score 0):

Provided `account` is the `DbSet<Account>` from your `DbContext` or an `IQueryable<Account>` derived from he same, it will query the database using the index.  if you want to emulate `Find` (where the locally tracked entities are checked for the entity prior to querying the database) you can first check if `dbContext.Set<Account>().Local` contains the entity prior to querying the database.

Comment: How would I "first check if dbContext.Set<Account>().Local" contains the entity?  What operation is available to find this record using the mnemonic (other than the LINQ query in the OP)?

Comment: use the linq query on the `Local` collection of the DbSet or get more creative like creating a dictionary of account entities keyed by the mnemonic value

Comment: I get the general impression if I do this query on the DbContext, that it will feed through to the database and use the indexes to find the record.  What's the implication of doing the LINQ statement on the local copy?  Do you know if we're going to iterate through all the in-memory versions of the account, or is there some local operation that will make use of an index?